# sspi protocol setup for RAD 7.1

Tags: cvs, rad, cvsnt

How to setup sspi protocol for RAD 7 1 to access CVS Repository code. Any Idea to resolve this issue?
I tried to connect using cvsNt cilent. added entry in extnt.ini and tried to connect them form cmd line and it conencted from command line. But not succedd from RAD. showing error as

[image]

Comment: The CVS connection string shows you have `.` as the username. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes.. because we dont need username and password but system won't allow me to proceed until we give .